# Dynamically define range to sum by based on row number?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to replicate an anchored sumif (similar to excel). To illustrate, here's a sample dataset:

```
Tag  #1   #2
A    2    4
B    1    5
C    3    5
D    7    0
E    9    3
```

And I want the resulting output:

```
Tag    row_number  sum_#1   sum_#2
A      1           22       17
B      2           20       13
C      3           19       8
D      4           16       3
E      5           9        3
```

So effectively, using the row_number() function to base this summation off of. Or if there is another way of doing this, that's great also. I've been giving this a try for a while now and will post an update if I figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sum()` as a window function to do this:

```
select 
  Tag, 
  row_number() over (order by tag) as "row_number", 
  sum("#1") over (order by tag desc) as "sum_#1", 
  sum("#2") over (order by tag desc) as "sum_#2" 
from table order by tag;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fb01f/5)

With your sample data the output would be:

```
| tag | row_number | sum_#1 | sum_#2 |
|-----|------------|--------|--------|
|   A |          1 |     22 |     17 |
|   B |          2 |     20 |     13 |
|   C |          3 |     19 |      8 |
|   D |          4 |     16 |      3 |
|   E |          5 |      9 |      3 |
```